# Using Cufon outside the canvas associated to Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, cufon, fabricjs

I have a problem here when I try use Cufon lib outside the canvas that are associated to Fabric.js. I´m trying make a Text font selector in my application that will show the fonts avaliable to use. The selector will display the font name as sample of font (like Photoshop, etc). So, to build the sample names, I´m trying using Cufon to replace the font style, but the Fabric.js dont allow use outside the canvas. Fabric.js show the text that Cufon replace inside the canvas. Someone know how resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method to use Cufon outside fabric.js, but it is really a dirty hack.

First I've added another cufon.js to the page from github. Then i opened it in editor and did auto-rename of 'Cufon' to 'CufonBase'.

I've written a wraper function to registerFont, that calls it two times for Cufon, and CufonBase:

```
 var makeWrap = function(fn1, fn2){
  return function(){
    try{
      fn2.apply(this, arguments);
      return fn1.apply(this, arguments);
    }catch(ex){
      ErrorHandler.Exception(ex);
    }
  };
};

Cufon.registerFont = makeWrap(Cufon.registerFont, CufonBase.registerFont);
```

This overwrites base method of Cufon that loads font and calls CufonBase.registerFont also, so you don't have to modify your font js.

And then you can call:

```
CufonBase.replace('h1', {fontFamily: 'font_name'});
```

And it works for me.